# Prolog Inverse Predicate

Tags: prolog

I have the following statements in Prolog:

```
speak("Portuguese","Brazil").
speak("Portuguese","Africa").
speak("English","EUA").
speak("Spanish","Spain").
capital("Brasilia", "Brazil").
capital("Washington", "EUA").
capital("Madrid", "Spain").
```

I'm trying to get all countries that do not speak a language. For instance, getting all the coutries that do not speak Portuguese would return EUA and Spain. I tried the following code:

```
notSpeak(X) :- speak(_,Y), not(speak(X,_)),write(Y),nl,fail.
```

However, it just returns false. Someone could point me where the error is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog is a logic language (***Pro**gramming in **Log**ic*, get it?)

You simply make the statement and let the inference engine do its work:

```
not_speak( L, C ) :- % to find countries that don't speak language L
  speak(X,C),        % - find a country that speaks any language X
  L \= X .           % - provided that that language X is not language L
```

And finding all the solutions is easy:

```
not_speak_all( L, Cs ) :- findall( C , not_speak(L,C) , Cs ) .
```

Giving us [this program](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/slGJqGTx.pl).

```
not_speak( L, C ) :- speak(X,C), L \= X .

not_speak_all( L, Cs ) :- findall(C, not_speak(L,C) , Cs ) .

speak( portuguese , brazil         ) .
speak( portuguese , africa         ) .
speak( english    , usa            ) .
speak( spanish    , spain          ) .
speak( english    , united_kingdom ) .
speak( dutch      , netherlands    ) .
```

Comment: See comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

`not(speak(X,_))` should be `not(speak(X,Y))`. When called with `?- notSpeak("English").` your code says "they speak Portuguese in Brazil and no country speaks English" which is not true so it fails. You want it to say "They speak Portuguese in Brazil and Brazil does not speak English".

---

<strike>You could also do:</strike>

```
notSpeak(X) :- speak(Lang, Country), dif(Lang, X), write(Country),nl,fail.
```

<strike>"They speak Lang in Country, and Lang is different from the forbidden one".</strike>. Don't use this one; as @false's comment explains, "Canada speaks French, that's not English, therefore Canada does not speak English" is flawed.

Comment: That second solution, consider belgium with french, dutch, and german as languages. Now, `notSpeak/1` holds for all three such languages.

Comment: @false good point! Answer edited.